# How do we deduce Hasse bound of curve of genus $g$ from congruent zeta function?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $C$ be a curve of genus $g$.

I heard we can deduce Hasse bound
$$
|\sharp C(\mathbb{F}_{q}) - q - 1| \leq 2g\sqrt{q}
$$

from congruent zeta function of $C$.

How can we do that?

I only know the case of $g＝1$, elliptic curve case, this is equivalent to Riemann hypothesis of Weil conjecture for elliptic curves. This is equivalent to state that numerator's discriminant is less than $0$.But the same way does not apply to another genus.So I'm stuck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May be it would be easier to derive it, if you used the correct form of the the zeta function instead of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4117939/11619)? Anyway, you need the analogue of the Riemann hypothesis for curves. You don't need to learn about etale cohomology to prove it for curves. The Schmidt-Stepanov method is more accessible. Check out Stichtenoth's *Function fields and codes* or Rosen's *Number theory in function fields*.

Comment: In the case of elliptic curves the fact that the discriminant of the quadratic in the numerator is $\le0$ is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis. For higher degree polynomials (degree $2g$) you need more to able to deduce that all the zeros share the same magnitude $q^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. What about the case of genus is 0? In this case, genus 0 curve is birational to P^1, so it is overkill to use congruent zeta function. But I heard even in genus 0 case, we can use congruent zeta function（Ofcouse we can use Hasse bound result but I want to deduce the result from directly using congruent zeta func）,.

Comment: When $g=0$ the numerator is constant $1$? That is the only polynomial of degree $2g=0$ with the constant term $1$ :-)

Comment: From that , we cannot deduce genus 0 curve over Fq always has q＋1 rational points...（but we can deduce from Hasse bound）. Is it impossible to use congruent zeta function to deduce it directly?

Comment: Sure we can! We know the zeta function exactly!

Comment: [Look at this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures#The_projective_line).

Comment: Sorry, but from zeta function, how can we deduce genus 0 curve over Fq has q＋1 rational points?